# ios app store more than one company name

Tags: ios, app-store

does anyone know if it is possible to show more than one company name for an app in the ios app store?

The reason for this is, that we want to copperatively develop an app with  another company (workload should be distributed roughly 50%:50%) and so some could consider it 'unfair' if the application is only attributed to one company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company name is entered at the time of creating an Apple Developer account, therefore, whichever company submits the binary to Apple will have their name listed. You could, I assume, create a new shared account and put both company names in when asked.

Comment: interesting idea adding two company names on a new account, but i am not sure if apple would allow this, as they are quite strict in checking a companies name

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest entering both companies under "Copyright". Seller name is just that - a seller name, and, as [the answer from Jasarien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736103/ios-app-store-more-than-one-company-name/4736393#4736393) has said, it can only be entered at registration time. Copyright is, however, is specified per-app and is also displayed on the app store product page.